# Fast Eigenvalue and SVD Solver for Structured Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, svd

I am looking for a fast Eigenvalue and SVD solver for small dense structured matrices (Hankel and Toeplitz). I have searched for efficient implementations in libraries like MKL but I am not able to find anything specific to structured matrices. I found a set of interesting papers on the subject:

[Luk and Qiao, "A Fast Eigenvalue algorithm for Hankel matrices"](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(00)00084-7) which uses Lancoz tridiagonalization based on FFT and a QR like diagonalization of the tridiagonal matrix for computing eigenvalues with a complexity of $O(n^2\log(n))$.

[Luk and Qiao, "A fast symmetric SVD algorithm for square Hankel matrices"](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2007.05.027)

Do any of the libraries out there or any implementation you know of use this as I would like to reuse as much as possible? Are there any algorithms which achieve bounds better than this for structured matrices?

Comment: A cursory Google search yielded these two Matlab packages written by Sanzheng Qiao (from McMaster U): [(1)](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~qiao/software/gfhsvd/matlab/readme.html) - for general (rectangular) matrices and [(2)](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~qiao/software/takagi/matlab/readme.html) - for symmetric matrices. Is this more or less what you were looking for?

Comment: Are you looking to compute all singular values / eigenvalues, or just a few of them? Is the matrix low-rank / does it have clustered eigenvalues?

Comment: @GoHokies, Thanks for the links. I am not necessarily looking for the implementation of those methods by Qiao. More of a papers/library research on faster than $\mathcal O(N^3)$ SVD for Hankel\Toeplitz matrices.

Comment: @RichardZhang, for my purposes, the matrices are mostly low-rank, so I search for the algorithms revealing the first $k$ singular-values (+singular vectors) with controlled tolerance $\epsilon$ ($\sigma_k/\sigma_1<\epsilon$).

Comment: I wrote this paper on SVD of Loewner matrices, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/295857431_Fast_Singular-Value_Decomposition_of_Loewner_Matrices_for_State-space_Macromodeling. The idea is applicable to any matrix with low displacement rank, such as Toeplitz and Hankel.