# Lanczos algorithms for Hermitian system with Toeplitz kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, iterative-method, svd, numerics

Basically, I am trying to compute the SVD of a large Hermitian matrix $H$ using Lanczos iteration, while $H$ consists if a Toeplitz kernel $K$, which should be able to help speed up the matrix-vector computations(using FFT) over conventional Lanczos algorithms.

$$
H(i,j) = P_i * K_{ij}(i-j) * P^*_j
$$

In summary, I need the largest few eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$, and I was wondering which Lanczos algorithms exactly meet this demand? I notice the [PROPACK](http://sun.stanford.edu/~rmunk/PROPACK/) package, but it seems to me it's not designed for this specific case here and the fact that it's written in Fortran...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this question, regarding fast eigenvalue/SVD solver for structured matrices](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10842/20688), it was adviced by @GoHookies to look into the paper:

- [W. Xu, S. Qiao, "A fast symmetric SVD algorithm for square Hankel matrices", *Lin. Alg. Appl.*, vol. 428, no. 2–3, pp. 550–563, Jan. 2008](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2007.05.027)

that also has a follow-up

- [K. Brown, S. Qiao, and Y. Wei, "A Lanczos bidiagonalization algorithm for Hankel matrices,"  *Lin. Alg. Appl.*, vol. 430, no. 5–6, pp. 1531–1543, Mar. 2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2008.01.012)

Those papers describe techniques (or parts of the required algorithm) to speed-up the calculation of SVD for structured matrices. The application to Hankel matrices naturally extends to the Toeplitz kernel. In general, they use fast FFT-based matrix-vector products for structured matrices applied to Lanczos iterations.

There is also a [Matlab package](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~qiao/software/gfhsvd/matlab/readme.html) from the same group of authors available online (with some additional explanation and references) that implements their algorithms.

I personally played with this package for my applications, but I am still yet to confirm the benefits and claimed complexity savings (slow side work in progress).

Answer (score 3):

How large are we talking, here? If the problem can fit onto a single node, you can likely just solve it through Hermitian matrix computations and call it a day, see [SLEPc](http://slepc.upv.es/) for fast implementations of this. Note that SLEPc is written in C but has Fortran and Python wrappers as well.

Addressing your problem more directly: I do not know of any SVD/EVD solvers that will exploit your Toeplitz kernal and matrix structure without modification. That said, it shouldn't be hard to construct something like this yourself. A common method for extracting the largest eigenvalues (singular values) of a matrix is the Arnoldi method, usually implemented using [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/). Here, you can simplify modify the matrix-vector multiplication subroutine yourself to exploit the Toeplitz structure through an FFT, as you said.